# How do you send Javamail with Chinese characters?

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I have written servlet class and send mail class to send Javamail. The English message works fine, but now I want to send Chinese as well. I suppose you add UTF-8 in MimeMessage's setSubject and setText methods. I did that but all chinese characters were corrupted in my inbox.

Email message comes from user input in submit form.

Here is my servlet:

```
package com.lsp.web;

import com.lsp.service.Mailer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "contact", urlPatterns = {"/contact"})
public class ContactServlet extends SpringInjectedServlet {
    @Autowired
    private Mailer mailer;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String customerEmail = req.getParameter("email");
        String subject = req.getParameter("subject");
        String body = req.getParameter("message");
        String name = req.getParameter("name");

        body = "YOU HAVE A MESSAGE FROM " + name + "<" + customerEmail +">.\n" + body;

        String error = null;
        String succMess = null;

        try {
            javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress ia = new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(customerEmail);
            ia.validate();
            mailer.send(customerEmail, subject, body);
            succMess = "你的消息已成功发送";
            req.setAttribute("succMessage", succMess);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("sent.jsp").forward(req, resp);

        } catch (javax.mail.internet.AddressException ae) {
            error = "您指出的邮箱地址不存在";
            req.setAttribute("errorMessage", error);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
        catch (MessagingException mex) {
            error = "发送失败";
            req.setAttribute("errorMessage", error);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Mailer class(to send email):

```
package com.lsp.service;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

@Component
public class Mailer {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);

    public Mailer() {
        log.info("I'm newed.");
    }

    public void send(String custMail, String subject, String body) {
        String from = "jshao745@gmail.com";
        String to = "jshao745@gmail.com";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");


       //body = "YOU HAVE A MESSEGE FROM " + custMail + "." + body;

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("jshao745@gmail.com","SOMEPASSWORD");//change accordingly
                 }
            });


        try{
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");

            // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
            message.setText(body, "UTF-8");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        }catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate if someone could help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: UTF-8 isn't a subject, it's a charset. The subject should be whatever the email is about. If you're sending HTML you should say so in the content-type header.

Comment: You mean: message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");? What if both subject and message body contain Chinese?

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I mean text/html instead of text/plain. I misread about the subject.

Comment: I tried all, but still having the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To start, make sure your Java String objects contain the correct Unicode characters.  If you don't do the input character conversion correctly, you can end up with garbage in the String objects, which of course means garbage in the email message.

Also, you don't need to set the Content-Type header explicitly, the setText method will do that for you.

You might also want to read this list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: Your answer confuses me. I appreciate if you could give me some examples. I read the common JavaMail mistakes, but it didn't say anything about character conversion.

Comment: I appreciate if you can give me some examples.

Comment: The Servlet API is converting the bytes that come over the HTTP connection into characters that are returned in the Java String objects from (e.g.) the getParameter method.  I don't know how it does that; read the Servlet spec.  But you can check that those characters are correct, either by printing out the integer values of each Unicode character in the String and comparing with what you expect, or by comparing the String returned by getParameter to a constant String that you know has the correct value.  That will tell you whether the input conversion is being done correctly.

Comment: I deleted setHeader method, but subject and message still display weird characters.

Comment: The setHeader was unnecessary, but it wasn't the source of your problem.  Do what I suggested above.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. Could you please clarify your point?

Comment: I found the problem. HTTP servlet request was not encoded. After adding req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");, everything worked. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @user3014926: Why do you post this as a separate answer so the people will know what solved it for you?